# d3.js Stacked Bar Chart working for one dataset but not the other

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using d3 to graph a stacked bar chart seen here - http://jsfiddle.net/H6P6X/. This works great with no errors.

Although using the same source, just with a different dataset, I'm getting these errors

```
Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute y="NaN" 
Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute height="NaN"
```

Seen here -- http://jsfiddle.net/YwKtQ/.

I'd like for these errors to be fixed -- as I believe they're causing the data at 5:00 to break the graph. I have no idea why this is happening, as the first graph seems to be working great.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing one attribute informational at 5:00

I included it http://jsfiddle.net/YwKtQ/1/

```
{
    "Time": "4:00",
        **"informational": 1,**
        "critical": 1,
        "medium": 26,
        "low": 50,
        "high": 349
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! I missed this as I'm querying a db to get this info. Thanks again!